# C# AES1 encryption, why output is truncated?

Tags: c#, encryption

This code is used in some very old code, to encrypt API Keys. So I can't change too much. It works fine with short API key, but starts giving problem when the key is long.

```
internal class TestCrypto
{
    private static int mIterations = 2;
    private static int mKeySize = 256;

    private static string mHash = "SHA1";
    private static string mSalt = "This is test....";
    private static string mVector = "Test Vector only";

    public static string Encrypt(string value, string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return null;

        byte[] vectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mVector);
        byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mSalt);
        byte[] valueBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);

        byte[] encrypted;
        using (var cipher = new AesManaged())
        using (var _passwordBytes =
            new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, mHash, mIterations))
        {
            byte[] keyBytes = _passwordBytes.GetBytes(mKeySize / 8);

            cipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = cipher.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, vectorBytes))
            using (MemoryStream to = new MemoryStream())
            using (CryptoStream writer = new CryptoStream(to, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                writer.Write(valueBytes, 0, valueBytes.Length);
                writer.FlushFinalBlock();
                encrypted = to.ToArray();
            }
            cipher.Clear();
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string value, string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return null;

        byte[] vectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mVector);
        byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mSalt);
        byte[] valueBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);

        byte[] decrypted;
        int decryptedByteCount = 0;

        using (var cipher = new AesManaged())
        using (var _passwordBytes =
            new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, mHash, mIterations))
        {
            byte[] keyBytes = _passwordBytes.GetBytes(mKeySize / 8);

            cipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            try
            {
                using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = cipher.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, vectorBytes))
                using (MemoryStream from = new MemoryStream(valueBytes))
                using (CryptoStream reader = new CryptoStream(from, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    decrypted = new byte[valueBytes.Length];
                    decryptedByteCount = reader.Read(decrypted, 0, decrypted.Length);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }

            cipher.Clear();
        }
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted, 0, decryptedByteCount);
    }
}
```

Test using code below:

```
var e = TestCrypto.Encrypt("This is just a test with a string that is very long", "abcd1234");
Console.WriteLine(TestCrypto.Decrypt(e, "abcd1234"));
```

The output is truncated:

`This is just a test with a string that is very l`

---

Update: Based on the answers below, I have found a better way:

```
decryptedByteCount = reader.ReadAtLeast(decrypted, decrypted.Length, false);
```

Use `ReadAtLeast` instead of `Read` and my problem solved.

Comment: Ignoring the return value of `stream.Read` is probably the root of your problem here. To completely read a stream, you need to carry on calling `Read` until it returns `0`. It seems likely to me that `decryptedByteCount` will be a different value from `decrypted.Length`, indicating that you have not finished reading the stream.

Comment: the problem you're facing is likely due to the limited buffer size used when reading the decrypted bytes in the Decrypt method.

Comment: As usual the .net documentation is garbage as it doesn't say what happens when all the bytes have been read. When does the final block get processed? It requires special processing due to the padding. I think @spender is correct in that you must call Read repeatedly until it returns 0. But even in the correct case `decryptedByteCount` will be less than `decrypted.Length` because padding bytes will have been stripped off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to read the decrypted bytes in chunks instead of trying to read all of them at once.

check this out:

```
public static string Decrypt(string value, string password)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return null;

    byte[] vectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mVector);
    byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mSalt);
    byte[] valueBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);

    byte[] decrypted;
    int decryptedByteCount = 0;

    using (var cipher = new AesManaged())
    using (var _passwordBytes =
        new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, mHash, mIterations))
    {
        byte[] keyBytes = _passwordBytes.GetBytes(mKeySize / 8);

        cipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        try
        {
            using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = cipher.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, vectorBytes))
            using (MemoryStream from = new MemoryStream(valueBytes))
            using (CryptoStream reader = new CryptoStream(from, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                decrypted = output.ToArray();
                decryptedByteCount = (int)output.Length;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }

        cipher.Clear();
    }
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted, 0, decryptedByteCount);
}
```

Comment: [`Stream.CopyTo(Stream)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=net-7.0) would drastically reduce the complexity of this code.